c# with WPF - Error when access an array created by a worker thread
I want to load a very large set of data into an array of Paragraph using a worker thread. Unlike most other similar questions, I do not want to update the UI from this worker thread, I just want the worker thread to fill the array. When the thread is done, the WPF thread will then use the data in this array.
I get the error "The calling thread can't access this object because the object is owned by another thread" when, from the WPF thread, I try to access objects in the array created in the worked thread (which is not active anymore).
My first question was closed as being a duplicate, but the other similar question were about access the UI elements from the worker thread, which is not what I want to do.
Here's a simplified example of the code :
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadDoc();
        }

        void ReadDoc()
        {

            // Create the array of Paragraph that will contain all the formatted data.
            // This array can be huge.

            Paragraph[] doc = new Paragraph[1];

            // Read all the data and fill the array using another thread to keep the UI responsive

            Thread reader = new Thread(() => ReadData(doc));
            reader.Start();

            // Kludge (not using signals in this example)
            // Make sure the fake reading thread is done before continuing

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            // Display some of the data

            richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(doc[0]);

        }

        void ReadData(Paragraph[] doc)  // This is the worker thread
        {
            // For this example, create a simple fake data instead of reading the file

            doc[0] = new Paragraph();  // Create a new Paragraph and add a Run to it
            Run run = new Run();
            run.Text = "Test";
            doc[0].Inlines.Add(run);
        }

    }


If instead of an array of Paragraph I use an array of string, it works, but the formatting is stateful and therefore I must preformat the data in a single pass, which is why I use Paragraph and the worker thread.
Since it works with strings, I tried to serialize the Paragraphs, but I get an exception "A possible object cycle detected".
